# Click on post and redirect to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

When i click on post url on my site -> it redirect me to the homepage. Indeed the address changed with the post name, but it display the home page.

Site url: http://www.as-bidud.co.il/

I know that you will see the site language as problem to help but for see that problem - click on the "read more \ קרא עוד" button on the slider.

When i switched the theme to Twenty eleven - everything work fine.

I dont find the problem in the function.php

- I already turned off the plugins and turn on one by one and not found the problem
- I thought the problems come from the Custom Post Type UI plugin but...not

Pages url work fine.

.htacess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Single.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="main" class="sub-page">
            <div id="page-view">
                <h1 class="page-title"><span><?php wp_title ( '', true,'left' ); ?></span></h1>
                <div class="page-content">
                   <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>



                         <?php  endwhile;  ?>  
                          <?php endif; ?>   

        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The site doesn't appear to be working at all.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert try now... i played with him a little..

Comment: Is the problem just with that specific post, or with all posts?

Comment: All posts. only pages work good. i will add .htaccess file to the question if it will help.

Comment: In function.php i have some custom fields that i generate from plugin, but when i delete the content of function.php - it not fix the problem.

Comment: if you turn off pretty permalinks, does it work?

Comment: It is possible that the problem on the single.php file? i included him in the question.

Comment: Could be.  I would temporarily delete (or rename) single.php so Wordpress has to fall back to a different template.

Comment: Just rename? i need to write somthing in the start of the single.php file?

Comment: It should fall back to some other file (perhaps index.php) if it can't find single.php

Comment: So the topic need to be - single.php automaticlly from some reason redirected to index.php... cant find the solution.

Comment: No, that's not necessarily what's happening.  I'm just suggesting that for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: OMG. 5 hours. 5 hours for changing Single.php to single.php.

Answer (score 0):

OMG. 5 hours. 5 hours for changing Single.php to single.php. Lowercase. that's all.